# How can I share C# DllImport functions between files?

Tags: c#, dllimport

I've imported my C++ DLL functions into C# by following some online examples. The functions have to be declared as part of a C# class. But if I want to use these functions in other C# classes how can I share the declarations?

The best solution would be to import the C++ DLL functions into a general class and use this throughout my application.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I tried the suggestion below but now I'm getting the error "ImportSomeStuff is inaccessible due to its protection level" where I try to use the struct. Everything seems to be public, so what else can I try?

```
class ImportSomeStuff
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MyStruct
    {
        public uint nData;
    }

    public delegate void MyCallback(ref MyStruct myStruct);

    [DllImport("My.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public static extern bool AddCallback(MyCallback callback);

    [DllImport("My.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public static extern bool RemoveCallback(MyCallback callback);
}
```

(different file)

```
class DoSomeStuff
{
    public List<ImportSomeStuff.MyStruct> listStuff = new List<ImportSomeStuff.MyStruct>();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static class Native
{
    [DllImport("nativelib.dll")]
    public static extern int SomeFunction();
}
```

And then you could call this function from everywhere:

```
Native.SomeFunction();
```

Comment: Thanks. My functions also use a struct that I've declared in C#, but I'm now getting the error "[class] is inaccessible due to its protection level" where I use it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @parsley then make the structs public

Comment: @parsley72, so reference your structs like this: `ImportSomeStuff.MyStruct` instead of `MyStruct` only. It is a nested type.

Comment: @parsley72, OK, I see, make the `ImportSomeStuff` class `public`: `public class ImportSomeStuff` instead of `class ImportSomeStuff`.

Comment: Ah right, I didn't realise you could do that to the class. Thanks!

Comment: @parsley72, you can apply visibility modifiers to any members. If you don't, by default the class will be `internal` which means that it can still be accessed from within the same assembly but not outside. It has to be public if you want it to be accessible from other assemblies.

Answer (score 3):

They are static functions, so if you make them public you should be able to access them with `ClassName.FunctionName()`. At last that's how you do it with C functions.

But typically I don't make my native interop stuff public. I keep it internal in my interop assembly and write a public wrapper on top of it which fits C# style better.

Comment: Agreed. I want to do that when I have more time but this is just trying to get it to work!